# Java NetBeans: Why does my string array terminate prematurely?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, netbeans

I found the problem. Apparently, there were random spaces in some of the names in the csv file, which was causing breaks at the 257th entry, as well as several others later on. So, I just took out the spaces and everything works fine now. Thanks to all who tried to help.

I have this code that reads from a csv file, puts the values in String array, and prints them for me to see. It runs fine until it reaches the 257th member of the array (each member has 3 values: last name, first name, and birth year). Here is a functioning version of the code:

```
package testing.csv.files;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //.csv comma separated values
    String fileName = "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Data.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName); // TODO: read about File Names
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        inputStream.next(); //Ignore first line of titles
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next(); // gets a whole line
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

Now, when I change the line

```
 System.out.println(data);
```

To this:

```
 System.out.println(values[2]);
```

What I expected to happen was for only the birth years (3rd column) to be printed for every person in the array. However, it only prints out until the 257th person's birth year (out of over 18,000), and gives me the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at testing.csv.files.Test.main(Test.java:22)
 Java Result: 1
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The "java: 22" seems to be referring to the above snippet of code I posted above that I changed. I am not really sure what the problem is. If my syntax is wrong, why did it print at all? The only thing I can think of is that perhaps a string array can only handle 257 different people each with their own 3 values. If that were the case, then I would need some kind of larger version of string to hold all of my data. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is the problem somewhere in my syntax and loop?

Comment: you are calling inputStream.next() and your comment says //gets a whole line. if this is true, it is just because of pure chance. You should use inputStream.nextLine() to get the next line of your file

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two things in the `values` array, then the highest location that you can index into is `1`.

For arrays, you can only index into `size - 1` spots; that is, if your array was size ten, you could index into a location 9, or more verbose:  `array[9]`.

Change your indexing statement to this:

```
System.out.println(values[1]);
```

Comment: If you read what I wrote carefully, you'll see that I have 3 values for each member of the array, so I've already done what you are advising. If you have another idea, please let me know.

Comment: Not according to the split and the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.  I would verify that you have how many elements you have by printing the size of `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`String data = inputStream.next();` // next() can read the input only till the space

to:

`String data = inputStream.nextLine();` // nextLine() reads input including space between the words

Also better way is to iterate the array instead acess through index may be particular line in csv not containing the third column.

Comment: I tried this, but now none of the values were printed, and I got the error message:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at testing.csv.files.Test.main(Test.java:22)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: can u paste the csv line where the issue arise ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see the 257th record in the csv file. Would the split method create three tokens for it? If it should result in less than three tokens and you try to print the third token by typing

```
System.out.println(values[2]);
```

you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.